# PLSQL Developer bind variables from GUI like as Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

How can I bind variables in PLSQL Developer from GUI like as Oracle PL/SQL Developer?

Example: select :variable from dual;
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute queries with bind variables inside the "Test Window".
It isn't only for debugging: if you type and execute a query, a new tab showing the query results will appear.

The result grid is not as smart as the grid you can use in regular SQL Windows, but it does the job.

[image: Test Window executing a query with bind variables]

I did ask multiple times to the Pl/SQL Developers to add support for bind variables to the regular SQL Window but it seems they aren't much interested in doing it

Comment: In case one of the AllAround team happen to pass by, this really is one of the weaker features of PL/SQL Developer.  Having to revert to the Test window to run a SQL script isn't pretty, because you keep having to flip between the output-data and the script itself..  The reason the SQL window is nice to work in is exactly because you get to have both on screen at the same time.  If anything, it should be the parameters screen that is hidden on a different tab, not the SQL output!