# Using parameters in a simple query keeps asking me to use INTO

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need check some records, don't want to retype ID values everytime so I thought I'd use a simple parameter for the value. PL/SQL developer keeps giving an error and saying I need to use `INTO` clause.

Former questions about this very same problem are not helpfull, I wonder if we can't just use a parameter as in MSSQL to simplify a simple query *which is not in a stored procedure*.

The query I tried and got the error:

```
DECLARE
  P_COMPANYID INT;

BEGIN
  P_COMPANYID := 1935;

  SELECT * FROM COMPANY_SHAREHOLDER CS WHERE CS.ID_COMPANY = P_COMPANYID;

END;
```

Isn't there a way to avoid using INTO without extra variable definitions?

Comment: The rules are the for an anonymous PL/SQL block (which you've shown) as they are for a stored procedure or function. Have you looked at [bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46712078/266304)?

Comment: In PL/SQL, when you select something, you have to put the result in some variables, so you need to use the INTO.

Comment: Well then how does a simple select * from works? I don't put results in a variable there, it is probably handled behind. I just want to do the same.

Comment: The tool you use to submit the sql read the columns into variables and displays them to you. When you use PL/SQL you have to use the INTO, otherwise PL/SQL does not know what to do with them, nor where to put them.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use parameter in sql, it looks like that is what you are looking for. Here is an example on sample table EMP:

```
koen>select * from emp where ename = '&ENAME';
Enter value for ENAME: KING
old:select * from emp where ename = '&ENAME'
new:select * from emp where ename = 'KING'

   EMPNO ENAME    JOB             MGR HIREDATE         SAL    COMM    DEPTNO 
________ ________ ____________ ______ ____________ _______ _______ _________ 
    7839 KING     PRESIDENT           17-NOV-81       5000                10 

koen>
```

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/sql*plus-substitution-variables-define-variables-and-parameters-in-sql-queries) is an (old but very complete) blog explaining it all.